# SFML fps problems with window event polling

Tags: c++, sfml

I've started messing around with C++ and SFML 2.4 and liking it so far but I have run into a frustrating performance issue with even trying to move a simple white rectangle around the screen. Moving the sprite around is very jittery and "unplayable" even when using the delta time. It seems to be caused by polling for window events. When removed, everything is smooth as butter but events cannot be read (of course). Is there a problem with what I'm doing or anything that I can do to fix this?

Minimal example:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500, 500), "Testing");

    sf::Image pixelBuffer;
    pixelBuffer.create(100, 100, sf::Color::White);
    sf::Texture pixelTexture;
    pixelTexture.loadFromImage(pixelBuffer);
    sf::Sprite pixelSprite;
    pixelSprite.setTexture(pixelTexture);

    sf::Clock clock;
    while(window.isOpen()){
        //Poll for events
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)){
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
                window.close();
            }
        }
        //Update the sprite
        float delta = clock.restart().asSeconds();
        pixelSprite.move(sf::Vector2f(50, 50) * delta);
        //Draw the sprite
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        window.draw(pixelSprite);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you say that pollEvents causes fps drops but you don't even include the function in the question. Make a minimal fully working example. And you probably don't want to restart the clock every iteration.

Comment: Actually I did if you look at the code snippet in the run() method and placed a comment on the method where it is called. I just removed the other methods for you to more easily read it.

Comment: doesn't look like a source of the problem, post a minimal complete example that I can copy and compile

Comment: Just updated the example and tested, still the same issue.

Comment: cannot replicate

Comment: Hmm maybe it&#39;s hardware related then? Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Since you do not post a complete example I can only refer to my own experience. I faced this when not applying delta time. Does it somehow go back and forward a bit when rendering?

Comment: The code snippet above is my example. I am applying Delta time so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: The issue could be that "your" delta time is sometimes 1/60 seconds and sometimes 1/80 seconds. Instead of your deltatime, can you take a fixed timestep and use an accumulator? See chapter "The final touch" for details, https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance you don't have any game controller connected and are running this example under Windows?

If so, you're most likely suffering from a known bug that's been fixed in SFML's code repository. Just download and compile the latest version (`master` branch) from the [official repository](https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git), compile and install it and the issues should be gone.

As an alternative workaround, connect any game controller compatible with DirectInput (e.g. joystick or gamepad).

Comment: I'm currently using 2.4.2 (I downloaded it from the downloads page) but I could try recompiling it maybe and I am running this example under windows with visual studio. I just tried connect one gamepad and the stuttering persisted but seems to work fine when I have two gamepads connected? Is this a windows thing? Thanks!

Comment: Compiling the latest version (master branch) didn't fix it so I'll have to just plug in two gamepads for now as a temporary fix :/, must be my particular os/hardware configuration. Thank you for the help though!

Comment: @AaronShappell Really weird as that shouldn't happen anymore. So is the problem gone once there's at least one gamepad connected?

Comment: Connecting only one gamepad doesn't seem to change the stuttering, plugging in two fixes it. I'll have to try it on some other systems.

Comment: @AaronShappell That's really odd and certainly not the original problem.